# Creating custom button class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, custom-controls

I'm trying to create custom button class for my android app

```
public class TicTacButton extends Button
```

I've set all the constructors inside the `TicTacButton` and created custom methods and properties. In my main activity, I've tried to initialize the Buttons as

```
TicTacButton btn = (TicTacButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

I'm getting a

> java.castClassException. android.widget.Button cannot be cast to
>   com.example.tictactoetitan.TicTacButton

I tried changing my xml file as

```
<TicTacButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
```

It didn't work.

Comment: Instead of using ``TicTacButton`` you should use full package name ``your.package.TicTacButton`` in layout.

Comment: You're also going to have to post the xml for button1.  What you posted defined button2.  How can we tell whether you defined button1 with a Button tag or a TicTacButton tag?

Comment: Using the full package name in the XML file fixed it.

Comment: @harism you should turn your comment into an answer so the OP can mark it "accepted."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the full package name in the XML file fixed it.

```
<com.example.tictactoetitan.TicTacButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
```